# How to catch custom exception of python site by boost::python

Tags: python, c++, boost, active-directory

Using python ldap to connect with the ldap server, everything are fine but I have no idea how to identify the specific exception thrown by the python ldap.There are many customize exception from the python ldap, like "ldap.SERVER_DOWN", "ldap.SIZELIMIT_EXCEEDED", "ldap.TIMEOUT" and so on.

example codes:

```
#include <iostream>

#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB

#include <boost/python.hpp>

int main()
{

  namespace bp = boost::python;
  try{
      Py_Initialize();
      bp::object main_module = bp::import("__main__");
      bp::import("ldap");
      bp::import("ldif");
      bp::object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");
      bp::exec("import ldap,ldif\n"
           "l = ldap.initialize('ldaps://RIO-PC')\n"
           "l.whoami_s()\n",
           main_namespace);
      //do something
  }catch (boost::python::error_already_set const &) {
  if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
      //find out it is exception "ldap.SERVER_DOWN"?
  }
      PyErr_Clear();
  }catch (std::exception const &ex) {
      std::cout<<ex.what()<<std::endl;
  }
}
```

How could I know which exception the python ldap thrown?I can print out the messages by "format_exception" but this solution is far from ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PyErr_GivenExceptionMatches`:

```
object LdapServerDownException = bp::import("ldap").attr("SERVER_DOWN") ;

# ...

PyObject *e;
if ((e = PyErr_Occured())) {
    if (PyErr_GivenExceptionMatches(e, LdapServerDownException.ptr())) {

    }
}
```

See http://misspent.wordpress.com/2009/10/11/boost-python-and-handling-python-exceptions/